# Divide a number - Multiple levels - Sum of all numbers equal to input number - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i divide a number multiple levels, i have a number and a list with 3 values, step 6 has the expected output, but i am not able to get it

```
Number = 500 
Divide=[5,6,9]
```

**Step1:**

Get the number and divide by sum of numbers in divide list

```
500/ (5+6+9) = 25
```

**Step 2:**
  Multiply the number we got as output with each number in divide list

```
25 *5 = 125 25* 6 = 150 25* 9 = 225
```

**Step 3:**
    print the number and the each of result we got in step 2

```
500 125  
500 150  
500 225
```

**Step 4:**
    Take every number we got in step 2 and divide that as follows

```
125 / (5+6+9) = 125/20 = 6.25
```

**Step 5**

```
6.25 * 5 = 31.25
6.25 * 6 = 37.50
6.25 * 9 = 56.25
```

**Step 6:**
Take 150 and 225 from step 3 and do the same thing from step 4 to step 6 and print as follows which is the final output,

```
500 125 31.25
500 125 37.50
500 125 56.25
500 150 37.5
500 150 45
500 150 67.5
500 225 56.25
500 225 67.5
500 225 101.25
```

For this i am able to get the first level with the following code

```
number = 500
divide=[5,6,9]
for i in divide:
    j=(number/sum(divide))*i
    print (number, j)
```

**Output:**

```
500 125.0
500 150.0
500 225.0
```

How can i proceed to get the next level of numbers as displayed in Step 6

```
**Expected Output 2**
    500 125 31.25
    500 125 68.75 #31.25+37.5
    500 125 125 # 68.75+56.25
    500 150 37.5
    500 150 82.5 #37.5+45
    500 150 150 # 67.5+82.5
    500 225 56.25
    500 225 123.75 #56.25+67.5
    500 225 225 # 123.75+101.25
```

**Output 3:**

```
    500 125 31.25
    500 125 68.75 #31.25+37.5
    500 125 125 # 68.75+56.25
    500 150 45 # this is 2nd set and the multiplication should start from 2nd number in divide list 6 9 5
    500 150 112.5 #45+67.5
    500 150 150 # 112.5+.37.5
    500 225 101.25  # this is 3rd set and the multiplication should start from 3rd number in divide list 9 5 6
    500 225 157.5 #101.25+56.25
    500 225 225 # 157.5+67.5
```

Comment: yes?  What is your problem exactly?

Comment: i am not able to get the result i am looking for

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

You just need some nested loops and an interim list for your results from your first looping pass.

```
number = 500
divide=[5,6,9]
interim = []
for i in divide:
    j=(number/sum(divide))*i
    interim.append(j)
    print (number, j)

for j in interim:
    for i in divide:
        k = j/sum(divide)*i
        print (j, k)
```

This returned the following for me

```
500 125.0
500 150.0
500 225.0
125.0 31.25
125.0 37.5
125.0 56.25
150.0 37.5
150.0 45.0
150.0 67.5
225.0 56.25
225.0 67.5
225.0 101.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple of `list` comprehensions, you could achieve what you want.

Breaking down the code through **each step**:

```
Number = 500 
Divide = [5,6,9]

step1 = Number/sum(Divide)

step2 = [step1 * i for i in Divide]

for i in step2:             # step3
    print('{} {}'.format(Number, i))

step4 = [i / sum(Divide) for i in step2]

step5 = [[i * j for i in step4] for j in Divide]

k = 0                       # step6
for i in step2:
    for j in step5[k]:
        print('{} {} {}'.format(Number, i, j))
    k += 1
```

Output:

```
500 125.0
500 150.0                                                   
500 225.0                                                   
500 125.0 31.25                                             
500 125.0 37.5                                              
500 125.0 56.25                                             
500 150.0 37.5                                              
500 150.0 45.0                                              
500 150.0 67.5                                              
500 225.0 56.25                                             
500 225.0 67.5                                              
500 225.0 101.25
```

Solution to the **updated** question:

```
Number = 500 
Divide = [5,6,9]

step1 = Number/sum(Divide)

step2 = [step1 * i for i in Divide]

for i in step2:             # step3
    print('{} {}'.format(Number, i))

step4 = [i / sum(Divide) for i in step2]

step5 = [[i * j for i in step4] for j in Divide]

k = 0                    # step6
for i in step2:
    sum = 0
    for j in step5[k]:
        sum = sum + j
        print('{} {} {}'.format(Number, i, sum))
    k += 1
```

Output (2):

```
500 125.0
500 150.0                                                   
500 225.0                                                   
500 125.0 31.25                                             
500 125.0 68.75                                             
500 125.0 125.0                                             
500 150.0 37.5                                              
500 150.0 82.5                                              
500 150.0 150.0                                             
500 225.0 56.25                                             
500 225.0 123.75                                            
500 225.0 225.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, is there a way to add the last column numbers and display them? edited the question and added the 2nd output

Comment: is there a way to multiply numbers in an order ? . Edited the question as well, pls see the output 3

Comment: "Is there a way.."- yes there is a way. I don't find anything good doing this. You can do this, that and everything, but I doubt what's the practical use of doing these stuffs. Also, stack overflow does not provide code writing services (Note the downvotes on your question). What we do is correcting the code and probably devising better methods.

Comment: yes,correct, i am just learning other ways of doing by asking other devs here since i am new to this

Comment: i tried numpy roll to make this work but i cant, any help on this would be appreciated